# Take decision on field value and fetch records from different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 Tables in Database.

**Table 1 :  users**
 id, name, email, password, singleCourse, userType,

**Table 2 : userCourses**
 id, fk_user_id, course_name

userType can be 1 or 2.

**Now if userType = 1**

Keep fetching from users table.

**And if userType = 2**

Fetch from userCourses Table which contains multiple records.

Need help with query logic.

Query should not fetch records from userCourses table until and unless there is a need.

Can It be done using CASE WHEN THEN ?

**Here is something I have tried:**

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name.user,email.user,password.user,userType.user,
fk_user_id.course,course_name.course 
FROM  CASE userType.user WHEN 1 THEN FROM users.u 
WHEN 2 THEN users.user INNER JOIN userCourses.course 
ON (user.id = userCourses.fk_user_id)");
```

**Sample Data:**

**userCourses**

```
1, John, john@test.com, 123456, 1, PHP
2, Nick, nick@test.com, 654321, 2, ''
```

**userCourses:**

```
1, 2, JAVASCRIPT
2, 2, C++
3, 2, Jquery
```

**Desired Output:**

I simply want to fetch user courses, but using desired table, query should not go to another table for checking records if usertype = 1

Comment: I have tried CASE but I m not getting the syntax

Comment: Can you show us some code that you tried?

Comment: At least provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Alright I am providing query

Comment: @peterm Please check my post

Comment: @CodeHunter I don't see any sample data nor the desired output. If you need help just dump (or make up) a few lines for of each table and post what you expect to get from the query in tabular form or better yet create [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: @peterm Please check sample Data,

Comment: @CodeHunter *I simply want to fetch user courses, but using desired table* It's absolutely unclear. That why I asked to show data and desired output in the first place. Can you spend a few seconds more and show desired output based on that sample data?

Comment: I can easily fetch an output. But my logic is I want query to behave fast. It should check for the userType first. If userType = 1 .. Ok dont go to another table for checking records, avoid join in that case, If userType = 2, Ok now you can fetch from another table.

Comment: It looks like your second table `userCourses` doesn't have any references to users with `userType = 1`

Comment: @peterm See its a very simple logic. I just want a syntax. My query is already in good shape. And userCourse doesnt have a reference to users with field = fk_user_id

Answer (score 0):

I have posted sample queries as below, modify as per your required

```
SELECT
(CASE field1
WHEN 'A' THEN 'value is A'
WHEN 'B' THEN 'value is B'
ELSE 'value is neither A or B'
END)
FROM your_table;
```

or

```
SELECT
(CASE
WHEN (field1 IS NULL) THEN 'value is NULL'
WHEN (field1 = 1) THEN 'value is 1'
ELSE 'value is neither NULL or 1'
END)
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: You didn't mentioned the second table in your query. Please check my updated Post

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't provide the desired output for unknown reason, it looks like all you need is this

```sql
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email, u.password, u.userType, 
       COALESCE(NULLIF(u.singleCourse,''), c.course_name) course
  FROM users u LEFT JOIN userCourses c
    ON u.id = c.fk_user_id
```

or

```sql
SELECT id, name, email, password, userType, singleCourse course
  FROM users
 WHERE usertype = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT u.id, name, email, password, userType, c.course_name
  FROM users u JOIN userCourses c
    ON u.id = c.fk_user_id
 WHERE usertype = 2
```

Sample output:

```
+------+------+---------------+----------+----------+------------+
| id   | name | email         | password | userType | course     |
+------+------+---------------+----------+----------+------------+
|    2 | Nick | nick@test.com |   654321 |        2 | JAVASCRIPT |
|    2 | Nick | nick@test.com |   654321 |        2 | C++        |
|    2 | Nick | nick@test.com |   654321 |        2 | Jquery     |
|    1 | John | john@test.com |   123456 |        1 | PHP        |
+------+------+---------------+----------+----------+------------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe280/5)** demo

Comment: In your query the control is going to check records in userCourse table everytime, even if the userType = 1

Comment: Your output is generated perfect but the logic is not helping me. Because i have to take differents conditions in different tables

Comment: 1) You can't conditionally join tables. 2) In the my first example it will join only existing rows on the right side of the outer join. It won't hurt performance in any way.

Comment: Basically it will hurt performance in my case. Because I am doing alot of calculations in my query. And that query+data is confidential too. So i have to take a condition on userType =1 and different condition on userType = 2

Comment: Again it won't hurt (benchmark it before you say so). But anyway, if you don't want to go with outer join your **only** bet is `UNION` as shown in my second example if you need combined resultset. This way you process it independently and then combine the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Updated post/codes:

```
<?php
 $query = mysqli_query("SELECT userType from user") or die("err:". mysqli_error());  
 $x = 1; 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
 {
    $userType[$x] = $row['userType']; // fetch all the userType in your table and put in an array
    $x++;
 }

for($x = 1; $x <= count($userType); $x++)
 { 

      if($userType[$x]="1") // determines if the user is "1" 
      { 
         $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM user") or die("Error" . mysqli_error());
      }
      else
      { 
            $query = mysqli_query("SELECT u.*, c.* FROM user u LEFT OUTER JOIN userCourse c ON u.id = c.fk_user_id") or die(mysqli_error());
      }

      while(mysqli_fetch_array($query))
      {
        //code here whatever data you want to show
      }
 }
```

Hope this helps. Apology for the earlier code.

Comment: How did you got $userType value ?